# Change the view in the reset password email using Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-mail

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and I'm working now on the reset password option on my CRM.

my CRM is multi-language therefore I need to change the email template / the view that sent to the customer based on his language, actually, I just need to change from RTL to LTR - this value is set on a cookie that called "user_direction".

I'm using the Laravel default bootstrap auth that includes ResetPassword class.

this is what is have now:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class ResetPassword extends Notification
{
    public $token;

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $url        = url('password/reset',$this->token);
        $subject    = trans('global.reset_password_email_subject'); 
        $greeting   = trans('global.reset_password_email_greeting'); 
        $line_01    = trans('global.reset_password_email_line_01'); 
        $action     = trans('global.reset_password_email_action'); 
        $line_02    = trans('global.reset_password_email_line_02'); 

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject($subject)
            ->greeting($greeting)
            ->line($line_01)
            ->action($action, $url)
            ->line($line_02);
    }
}
```

and this is the idea of what i want to have but i dont know how to write it right:

```
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $url        = url('password/reset',$this->token);
        $subject    = trans('global.reset_password_email_subject'); 
        $greeting   = trans('global.reset_password_email_greeting'); 
        $line_01    = trans('global.reset_password_email_line_01'); 
        $action     = trans('global.reset_password_email_action'); 
        $line_02    = trans('global.reset_password_email_line_02'); 

        $view = "notifications::email";
        if($request->cookie('user_direction') == "rtl"):
            $view = "notifications::email-rtl";
        endif;

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->view($view)
            ->subject($subject)
            ->greeting($greeting)
            ->line($line_01)
            ->action($action, $url)
            ->line($line_02);
    }
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the reset passwords view by overriding the function in

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords` Trait.

Simply add the following function in class

`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController`

modify your view.

```
/**
 * Display the password reset view for the given token.
 *
 * If no token is present, display the link request form.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string|null  $token
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Saravanan Sampathkumar, it's not what i mean, i want to change the mail that sending to the user to reset his password, the content of the mail is a view and i want to change this view if the user using RTL or LTR

Answer (score 0):

after watching some tutorials on youtube it worked for me, i wrote it this way:

first I add **"use Cookie;"**

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $user_language_direction = Cookie::get('user_direction');

    $url        = url('password/reset',$this->token);
    $subject    = trans('global.reset_password_email_subject'); 
    $greeting   = trans('global.reset_password_email_greeting'); 
    $line_01    = trans('global.reset_password_email_line_01'); 
    $action     = trans('global.reset_password_email_action'); 
    $line_02    = trans('global.reset_password_email_line_02'); 

    $view       = "notifications::email";
    if($user_language_direction == "rtl")
        $view   = "notifications::email-rtl";

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->view($view,array())
        ->subject($subject)
        ->greeting($greeting)
        ->line($line_01)
        ->action($action, $url)
        ->line($line_02);
}
```